# How to access a #document(virtual document) in VBA(excel 2007)

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I just started to use vba automation in IE and at the moment i am trying to make a routine to make my job easier at work. For that i have to complete every morning a site. Until now i managed to log in the site and click some buttons and i am stuck when i need to select a tab; there are 3 tabs and one of them gets selected automatically, the third one actually, and i need to select the second one (Inserimento Giustificativi):

[the 3 tabs i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbLOl.png)

Next i will give you the code of the tabs:

```
<div id="TabContainer1_header" class="ajax__tab_header">
            <span id="TabContainer1_TabPanel3_tab" class="">
             <span class="ajax__tab_outer">
              <span class="ajax__tab_inner">
               <span id="__tab_TabContainer1_TabPanel3" class="ajax__tab_tab">Console Operativa</span>
              </span>
             </span>
            </span>
            <span id="TabContainer1_TabPanel1_tab" class="">
             <span class="ajax__tab_outer">
              <span class="ajax__tab_inner">
               <span id="__tab_TabContainer1_TabPanel1" class="ajax__tab_tab">Inserimento Giustificativi</span>
             </span>
            </span>
           </span>
           <span id="TabContainer1_TabPanel2_tab" class="ajax__tab_active">
            <span class="ajax__tab_outer">
             <span class="ajax__tab_inner">
              <span id="__tab_TabContainer1_TabPanel2" class="ajax__tab_tab">Giustificativi Generici</span>
             </span>
            </span>
           </span>
</div>
```

And here is the code i made until now (pretty basic really):

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim ele As Object

    Set objIE = Nothing

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "sia.comdata.it/opera"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    objIE.document.getElementById("UserName").Value = "username"

    objIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = "$password"

    objIE.document.getElementById("LoginButton").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

    objIE.document.getElementById("palla").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    objIE.document.getElementById("content_GestioneOperativo").getElementsByTagName("a")(2).Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))

End Sub
```

I tried all the methods above and habe been searching on internet for a week for a solution but nothing, all the time i get the error run-time error 91 or that the action is not supported.

Also i noticed that when click manually one of the tabs the ClassName "ajax__tab_active" moves itself to the class of the tag i selected and the ClassName that was populated with "ajax__tab_active" remains blank i don't know if it helps, just that i found it strange.

Any tips would be helpful since i am a begginer and i really have no idea what else to try since i'm writting here,

Thank you.

*I'm editing my question since, doing a lot more tries, i noticed that i can't access a part of the source code. At some point in the source code there is a tag named iframe and immediately after it is #document, it seems that i can't access anything under #document in any way, googling it i understand it is a virtual document embedded in the source code, but i still have no idea how to access it:

[Virtual document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPRd8.jpg)

That's how the source code look and the line selected is what i need to get,

Thank you.

Comment: To locate the tab, you can play with `GetElementByTag("span")` and the property `InnerText` to locate the tab which InnerText is `Inserimento Giustificativi`. And then, maybe a Click would work?

Comment: I feel like this could be an *[`X-Y Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/370758)*.   **Backing up** a bit, could you explain more about what you're *actually* trying to do, as in, *the **"End Goal"***?

Comment: First Thank you for your answers. foxfire i tried the tip you gave me like this:     
    
    Set ele = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    
    For Each span In ele
        If ele.innerText = "Inserimento Giustificativi" Then
        ele.Click
        End If
    Next
   
  but it gives me the error that the action is not supported, did i write something wrong?

Comment: Ty for your answer ashleedawng. Im not sure what problem you're reffering to but the end goal of the routine is to to select some names (that would appear in the tab that i cant figure out how to select) and for those name i need to fill out some boxes with data that i get from another excel file (for example when he came to work es:08:00 and how many hours he stayed at work es: 04:00) and then i would have to click another button to validate the datas inserted in the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue.
To be able to access the data under #document it seems that all i had to do was to login and then navigate to the site a line above it, that is: https://sia.comdata.it/opera/GestioneOperativo/Giustificativi.aspx , after that everything went smoothly.